# Can I map over an array and turn variable into several different values?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to make variable i equal to 1,2,3,4. As this is then used as part of the name of div that needs to be hidden/shown.

Is there that this can be implemented easily? I have been trying with loops, mapping over array etc. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
function listenForIconModalChange() {
  // var modalNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  // for (i = 0; i <= modalNumbers.length; i ++);

  $('div[data-index^="icons_icon_"' + i + '"_modal_img"]').hide();
  $('div[data-index^="icons_icon_"' + i + '"modal_img_adobe"]').hide();
  $('div[data-index^="icons_icon_"' + i + '"_modal_imga"]').hide();
  $('div[data-index^="icons_icon_"' + i + '"_modal_copy"]').hide();
  $('div[data-index="icons_icon_"' + i + '"_modal"]').show();

  enableIconModalDropdown = $('select[name="icons_icon_' + i + '"modal"]');

  var enableIconModal = enableIconModalDropdown.val();
  if (enableIconModal == 1) {
    $('div[data-index^="icons_icon_"' + i + '"_modal_img"]').show();
    $('div[data-index^="icons_icon_"' + i + '"modal_img_adobe"]').show();
    $('div[data-index^="icons_icon_"' + i + '"_modal_imga"]').show();
    $('div[data-index^="icons_icon_"' + i + '"_modal_copy"]').show();
  }

  enableIconModal1Dropdown.change(function() {
    $('div[data-index^="icons_icon_"' + i + ']').hide();
    $('div[data-index="icons_icon_"' + i + ']').show();

    var enableIconModal = enableIconModal1Dropdown.val();
    if (enableIconModal == 1) {
      $('div[data-index="icons_icon_"' + i + ']').show();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: `for (i = 0; i <= 4; i ++)` would seem to do what you need. Although I'd suggest that using classes more effectively could turn this in to about 5 lines of code.

Comment: I think that handler (`onchange`) will end with the last value of `i`.  I mean, when that handler is triggered will always use the last assigned value in `i`.

Comment: Thanks Rory, but Ele is right. The value of `i = 4` everytime the handler is called

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ES6 template string, like this:

```
$(`div[data-index^="icons_icon_${i}_modal_img"]`);
```

Or if you want to keep your syntax, you have to remove some quotes:

```
$('div[data-index^="icons_icon_' + i + '_modal_img"]');
```